# Save File Dialog boxes in VB WPF

Tags: wpf, openfiledialog, savefiledialog

In Windows Forms it seems there are precreated dialog boxes for opening and saving files.
That is greyed out in the WPF toolbox.
Is there an easy way to create such a dialog box using WPF?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you have to add a reference to `Microsoft.Win32` and use the `OpenFileDialog` class which will initiate the same OS dialog you'd get from Winforms...

```
var ofdXlsDataSource = new OpenFileDialog
{
    CheckPathExists = true,
    CheckFileExists = true,
    Multiselect = false,
    Filter = "Excel documents (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx",
    RestoreDirectory = true
};

if (ofdXlsDataSource.ShowDialog() == true)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [OOkii Dialogs](http://www.ookii.org/software/dialogs/), it's a free library that supports a large range of "standard" and custom dialogs designed for both Winforms and WPF.